# Monero Fork syncing problem

Tags: monerod

I have forked Monero and running a private blockchain, everything was fine but sometimes what happening is some nodes got sync problem. The actual block height in the network was 4015 but some nodes shows the block height 3956. When I do status on the daemon of the problem node it states 100% synced, but actually the node is not fully synced with the network as the network height is 4015.

When I ran pop_blocks command in the daemon the node get synced property, again after some days I am getting the same problem. Is there any permanent solution for this issue

Comment: How many nodes are in the network? Are you using exclusive peers? Are they all online and connected? Have you checked which nodes the problem node(s) is/are connected to? How many nodes are mining?

Comment: There are around 15 nodes in the network. Yes, I am using exclusive peers for 4 nodes and all the nodes are online. Yes, I have checked the nodes which the problem nodes are connected to and those nodes take the problem node's height. There are around 3 nodes mining